# is giving and taking of interest haraam in islaam?

Tags: tafseer

mostly people take interest from banks and use them in useless work and says that its o.k.Please specify the verses of quran which says it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Usury (Charging Interest) Forbidden in the Quran:**

> Surah Al-Baqara, Verse 275 - 277:
>   Those who swallow down usury cannot arise except as one whom Shaitan has prostrated by (his) touch does rise. That is because they say, trading is only like usury; and Allah has allowed trading and forbidden usury. To whomsoever then the admonition has come from his Lord, then he desists, he shall have what has already passed, and his affair is in the hands of Allah; and whoever returns (to it) -- these are the inmates of the fire; they shall abide in it.
>   Allah does not bless usury, and He causes charitable deeds to prosper, and Allah does not love any ungrateful sinner.Surely they who believe and do good deeds and keep up prayer and pay the poor-rate they shall have their reward from their Lord, and they shall have no fear, nor shall they grieve.

Allah Says That He and His Messenger **Wages War** against those who use interest:

> O you who believe! Be careful of (your duty to) Allah and relinquish what remains (due) from usury, if you are believers.But if you do (it) not, then be apprised of war from Allah and His Messenger; and if you repent, then you shall have your capital; neither shall you make (the debtor) suffer loss, nor shall you be made to suffer loss.

Money was intended to used for exchange, not to increase on interest. Plus, if one person gives all his loans then he ends up with all the money.

If you'd like to know more concerning reason's why interest can be harmful, watch these video documentaries: [Money as Debt](http://youtu.be/jqvKjsIxT_8), [Money as Debt 2](http://youtu.be/lsmbWBpnCNk)